# DevExpress CodeRush/Refactor - Context Specfic 'Tips'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, devexpress, coderush

I decided to give [CodeRush/Refactor](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/index.xml) a go (after a rial of Resharper) and one problem I have is that CodeRush/Refactor puts a lot of 'artifacts' in my code window.

By 'artifacts', I mean icons/glyphs next to every Method, Property and Field name, green 'return key style' icons next to every property getter and boxes around getter methods.

Is there a way to make this contextual rather than visible all the time - perhaps only appear when I hover over a line?

Is there a clean up/rearrange the `usings` feature?

Comment: I don't see what you're talking about...

Comment: You seem to be asking several questions at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor! Pro will optimize your using directives. It can remove the ones you don't need, and sort them, either alphabetically or by length (aesthetically).

Note that if you have a using directive only present because there is a `<see cref="XYZ"/>` reference to something in that namespace, Refactor! Pro will not realize that part, and remove it if you ask it to optimize the directives.

As for the rest, no, there is apparently no way to make the information you mention only appear on hover.

Here's a tip for Refactor! Pro. Right-click your toolbar and select Customize, then click on the Keyboard button in the lower left of that dialog.

In the next dialog, search for the function CodeRush.Refactor, and bind it to Ctrl+Shift+R, I find this to be very helpful to get quick refactoring functions available. To optimize your using directives afterwards, simply place the cursor inside them and hit Ctrl+Shift+R to get the refactor popup.

Comment: I would suggest that you do as much of your CodeRush/RefactorPro configuration as possible in their own options screen. (DevExpress\Options [CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+O] IDE\Shortcuts) This will allow you to easily take those settings with you either to another machine, or between upgrades of VS.

Comment: The default Refactor Key is set to CTRL+`.

I prefer to set this to ALT+1 and there are other people (Mark Miller included) who set this to NUM0

Answer (score 4):

Not that I know of. I'd suggest asking on [support.devexpress.com](http://support.devexpress.com/). I find them very responsive.

Comment: Yes, definitively, if for no other reason than to make sure those features ends up on a todo list. I have disabled many of those things for the same reason, they add noise to my code editor, but it would be nice to be able to hover over a method and see the method icon, the metrics value, etc.

Comment: Also, Developer Express has one of the best support groups I've ever encountered, so sending them questions like that is basically a nobrainer.

Comment: Agreed. Every time I've had an issue or bug I've usually had a fix and test build within hours.

Comment: +1: Their forums are garbage but the response to their support tickets is worth every penny I made my boss pay for it :)

Comment: The Forums are Peer to Peer. It's even listed as such in the Community menu on their homepage. DX make a specific point of saying that whilst they do drop by from time to time. It's their customers who man said forums and as such, your milage may vary by product/forum.

Answer (score 1):

CodeRush has (in version 9.1 and higher) a toolbar (DXCore Visualise) which allows you to toggle various graphical overlays that it provides.

See half way down this blog post for details http://rorybecker.blogspot.com/2009/03/coderush-and-refactor-910-beta.html

**Update:** Since Joining DevExpress, I have [blogged the DXCore Visualize Toolbar in more detail](http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/rorybecker/archive/2010/07/26/The-DXCore-Visualize-Toolbar.aspx)